# Typescript instantiate typeof abstract class

Tags: typescript

This is my code:

```
abstract class BaseClass {}
class DerivedClassA extends BaseClass {}
class DerivedClassB extends BaseClass {}
const derivedClasses: (typeof BaseClass)[] = [DerivedClassA, DerivedClassB];
for (const c of derivedClasses) {
   const instantiatedObj = new c; // error: Cannot create an instance of an abstract class
}
```

I have an array of derived classes which I want to iterate and initiate each.
`(typeof BaseClass)[]` is not a suitable type. Removing it solves it. What's the correct type?

Comment: Don't declare the base class abstract? The whole point of an ABC is that it *isn't supposed to be* instantiated.

Comment: @JaredSmith Notice `a` is not actually abstract.

Comment: ...but *you* declared a's type to be that ABC. Just don't do that. None of this makes any sense. Make it the DerivedClass, or better yet an interface that the class implements.

Comment: @JaredSmith I'm dealing with a variable which I don't know its exact type but I know it's derived from an abstract class. How can I indicate that?

Comment: @JaredSmith and I want to be able to instantiate it.

Comment: Ah now it makes sense. I've indicated a solution in an answer. Please edit the information from your comments into the question itself.

Comment: Ok I've deleted my answer and voted to close the question. Please edit the question to meet [the site standards](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). "I'm dealing with a variable which I don't know its exact type but I know it's derived from an abstract class" how do you know that it extends the ABC? Why don't you know it's type? is it a function argument? If not then what? Why isn't that information in the question itself? I thought I understood what you wanted, given your responses on my answer I don't understand your question, and I'm starting to wonder if *you* understand it.

Comment: @JaredSmith Ok, check the question again and you may understand my scenario. I have an array of classes and I want to iterate over them and instantiate...

Comment: Why do you need to assign a type to derivedClasses at all? The compiler can infer it just fine and it will be an array of the union of the classes you pass in. Just remove that type annotation and [everything just works](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/IYIwzgLgTsDGEAJYBthjAgQmgpgYVXQQG8BfAKBTQwBEcoBLANxwBMDqBBBHADwhwA7Vhmxh8hDMQTAEAXgQBmBBSpE6jFu0mYe-ISKy4ORaSHkIALCsoB7QZASt6zNifEYFAbQ2vtXABoEXy13TABdAG5yADNbKAQAClh7R1gEWxinF1DJHDAAShJyBFKUh0QGCuBBCAZgAVYAeRAAKwtBHAB3JEiEAHp+nigoeIAuBDwawVtEWCgcBpwZQQQqyBrYZcyVmXBoODnJcgpSoA)

Comment: @JaredSmith Ok, removed it. Doesn't effect the quality of code.

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/wgZ9lW) meet your needs?  If so I could write up an answer; if not, what am I missing?  (Please @jcalz mention me if you reply or I probably won't be notified)

Comment: @jcalz Yes, Write an answer and I will accept. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [construct signature](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#construct-signatures) of the form `new (arg0: XXX, arg1: YYY) => ZZZ` or `{ new (arg0: XXX, arg1: YYY): ZZZ }` to represent an object that acts as a  class constructor on which you can use [the `new` operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new).  In the examples above, you'd pass it two arguments of type `XXX` and `YYY` and get a class instance of type `ZZZ`.

Since you want to call `new c()` with no arguments and expect the constructed instances to be assignable to `BaseClass`, the type you need is `new () => BaseClass`:

```
const derivedClasses: (new () => BaseClass)[] = 
  [DerivedClassA, DerivedClassB]; // okay

for (const c of derivedClasses) {
  const instantiatedObj = new c(); // okay
}
```

The compiler is happy to allow you to assign `DerivedClassA` and `DerivedClassB` to elements of `derivedClasses` because each of them can be used as a constructor that takes no arguments and produces an instance of a subtype of `Baseclass`.  And the compiler is happy to allow you to call `new c()` because the construct signature takes no arguments.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?jsx=0#code/IYIwzgLgTsDGEAJYBthjAgQmgpgYVXQQG8FgEBeBARgQF8AoFNDAERygEsA3HAEwIsAgghwAPCDgB2fDNjD5CGUiEoIATPSZKE7LrwFLMoidNlZcgoqVhqAzFqYB7KZAR8OPflYVgAXAgAFFI4AO5BAJSUAHwWCj4RANoAumqJel6GwgA0up4GPpjJANwMAGZOUEGwLm62TmXu+d5KOGBRxAwISLWInK4QwFIQnMCSfADyIABWaiHhsIERxQgA9KsITgDWwACeDHRAA)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```js
abstract class BaseClass {}
class DerivedClass extends BaseClass {}
const b: BaseClass = new DerivedClass();
```

DerivedClass can be treated as a BaseClass given that DerivedClass as the same methods/attributes as BaseClass. And if you want to return to Derived class, you can do this:

```js
if (b instanceof DerivedClass) {
    // use DerivedClass methods here
    b.customDerivedClassMethod()
}
```

Comment: I want to use `typeof BaseClass` and instantiate it.

Comment: @Parsa_Gholipour Why do you want it to be a type that by definition cannot be instantiated and then instantiate it?

Comment: @isaactfa Because I don't know its exact type. It's type of a derived class but I don't know which one.

Comment: @Parsa_Gholipour, as @isaactfa said, by definition, you cannot instantiate an abstract class. Another idea could be removing the `abstract` from the class definition

Comment: @AlexanderYammine Removing `abstract` doesn't make sense because it shouldn't be instantiable. I want to say for example `a` is type of one of derived classes of a base class and didn't find notations for that yet.